# Dual boot doesn't launch after I changed my laptop battery. Windows fires up automatically

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, system-installation, windows, battery

Dual boot(Windows10 and Ubuntu 20.04) was working fine on my laptop until recently when I decided to change the battery of my laptop. Now, on firing up my laptop, Windows10 boots on its own without even the grub boot menu screen. WHat should I do in this case? Only issue might be to add ubuntu OS back into the GRUB men. LMK if I am working and how must i proceed?

ps: disk partition still exists.